# Mysql native full text search performance

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, sphinx

I have Joomla `3.3.x` site which has 500+ articles and will be increased more in future. Joomla 3.x has `smart search` feature but its not work properly. However I want to implement full text search. My site is in Unicode (Bengali). I have seen `sphinx` search but as far i know `mysql 5.6+` has native `full text` indexing & search option. Now my question is

**If I use mysql (new coming) native full text indexing and search, will it harm my site performance**? I need to index only a table's two column (title & description) in entire database.

My site has no real time data so we don't need to index content frequently. For this small requirement Should I use `sphinx` or not?

Thanks

Comment: @3.14159265358... Really, since when?

Comment: @jeroen Joomla is a subset of PHP.  PHP might run Joomla, but Joomla doesn't necessarily run all PHP.  Here's a good article if you want specifics (see the chart): http://shoutex.com/blog/wordpress-vs-joomla-vs-drupal-choosing-a-cms/

Comment: `Joomla 3.3.x`, lucky you haven't provided a URL to your site else it could have been hacked. Please update to 3.4.5 immediately

Comment: @Lodder I'll update soon. However this is not my issue now. I need full text search info. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As long as your tables and columns match this MySQL requirement:

> Full-text indexes can be used only with InnoDB or MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

and you set proper `FULLTEXT` indexes, you should not face performance issues. Of course, in the end it depends on the final queries you use.

More on MySQL full-text search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

One way of queries optimizing: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: Yes my tables are InnoDB with `TEXT` fields to index. Can you give me some more information about native full text search's superiority over `sphinx`